# updating array of object properties using for of loop in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, object

```
 for(let post of posts){
        console.log("post",post.photoDetails)
        if(post['photoDetails']?.imageName){
            console.log(post.photoDetails === posts[0].photoDetails,"check equality") // true
            const getObjectParams = {
                Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: post.photoDetails.imageName
            }
            const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
            const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
            post["photoDetails"]["url"] = url
            // spread operator not working 
            // post["photoDetails"] = {
            //     ...post.photoDetails,
            //     url:url
            // }
            // replace complete post 
             post = {
                ...post,
                url:url
             }
            console.log(post)
        }
    }
 return res.status(200).json({
    'message': 'user Profile Details ',
    'posts' : posts
})
```

i am having following doubts

1. `post["photoDetails"]["url"] = url`  here photoDetails is my object ,I am trying to add key and value using bracket notation.Why it is not working?

> let a = {   "name": "dd" }
>
> a["sec"] = 3
>
> //  a  // a is having both name and sec but why in my case key is not
> getting added

2. Next i tried to  assign a new  object to photoDetails using spread operator .still my post is not updated i don't know why
3. I am unable to add to photoDetails so i tried to add a new key to my post and send.

   `post = {...post,url:url}` . Now inside for loop my log is showing as expected added an url key but in response (where i am sending posts using res object) we are getting old posts(non updated posts) .According my knowledge objects are reference types .If we change the reference any where it should effect the original .But why in my  case  `post = {...post,url:url}` the original posts is not getting effected even i updated post
4. Finally how to add url key to my photoDetails Object and send in response

## my posts object

```
let posts =  [{
    _id: "637d1016223653199f35a482",
    password: '$2b$10$s9dJHy/hcvnAoNZWryiGj.j3cMGYFwTerhS6JqhmQRj5ZlBUeQ/PW',
    gender: 0,
    __v: 0,
    profileDetails: {
      _id: "637d103b223653199f35a488",
      profileDetails: "637d1016223653199f35a482",
      __v: 0
    },
    familyDetails: {
      _id: "637d1083223653199f35a48e",
      fatherName: 'opll',
      fatheroccupation: 'farmer'
    },
    photoDetails: {
      imageName: '1669140955730signin_image.jpg',
      userId: '637d1016223653199f35a482',
      __v: 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify your code a bit:

```js
const posts = [{ }, { }];

console.log('log 1', posts);

for (let post of posts) {
  post["url"] = 'foo';

  post = {
    ...post,
    url: 'bar'
  }

  console.log('log 2', post);
}

console.log('log 3', posts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Now you can see that `post["details"]["url"] = 'foo';` actually works like you'd expect. In the final console log, you'll see `'foo'` returned.

So why doesn't it show `'bar'`?

Your `post = { ... stuff ... }` doesn't update the value in the array.
`post` is a reference to an object. It doesn't know about that array.

An array is nothing but a list of pointers to said objects:

```
const posts = [pointsToObjectFoo, pointsToObjectBar]
```

If you then iterate over said array, your object variable `post` is a copy of the *pointer*:

```
for (let post of posts) {
// `post`'s value is _also_ a pointer to objectFoo.
```

Now, when you assign a new object to `post`, you're *replacing* the pointer that's stored in `post`:

```
post = {} // objectBar
// post now points to objectBar
```

The array doesn't know that you updated that pointer somewhere else. Why should it?

Comment: Thanks ,
can you replace post['url'] to object insted of  primative types  (if you check my data photodetails is an object i am trying to add a key to my object  known as url )

Comment: `post["url"]` and `post["photoDetails"]["url"]` both work the same way...